# Where is the rofi configuration file?

Tags: arch-linux, rofi

Where is the rofi configuration file? The various manual/help files are wrong. They state that it is /etc/rofi.rasi but this file does not exist on my system. Furthermore, ~/.config/rofi is empty. The variable XDG_CONFIG_HOME is unset.

Obviously rofi is getting application information from somewhere because when it runs, it lists dozens of applications. The question is: where is getting that information from?

Note that the "configuration" information I am asking about here is the application startup commands that rofi uses to start applications. How does it know the names and command line startup for the applications that it starts? I am not asking about UI configuration settings, like what color is the menu or things like that.

My rofi activating binding is as follows:

set $menu rofi -show run

Comment: Which mode of rofi are you talking about? `rofi -show run`? `rofi -show drun`? Something else?

Comment: @Wieland I have edited the question to show that information.

Comment: Try `rofi -dump-config > config.rasi` to get a config template. Not sure if this helps, though.

Answer (score 1):

`rofi -show run` gets the list of executables from `$PATH`:

```
   run
       Shows a list of executables in  $PATH  and  can  launch  them  (optional  in  a  terminal).   Pressing  the  delete-entry  binding
       (shift-delete)  will  remove  this  entry from the run history.  Pressing the accept-custom binding (control-enter or shift-enter)
       will run the command in a terminal.
```

(from the man page of rofi).

> Where is the rofi configuration file? The various manual/help files are wrong.

If you have not created a config file, there is none, and rofi uses its default settings. You can create a config file with those settings by running `rofi -dump-config`:

```
       NOTE: In version 1.4.0 we support configuration in a new format, a config for this can be generated by: rofi -dump-config  >  con‐
       fig.rasi
[...]
       -dump-config

       Dump the current active configuration, in rasi format, to stdout and exit.  Information about the rasi format can be found in  the
       rofi-theme(5) manpage.
```

(also from the man page).